# How to graph this problem?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant bounded by the graph of $y=2\sqrt{x}$, the horizontal line $y = 6$, and the $y$-axis. Region $R$ is the base of a solid. For each $y$, where $0 \le y \leq 6$, the cross section of the soild taken perpendicular to the $y$-axis is a rectangle whose height is 3 times the lenght of its base in region $R$.  This is from 2010 AP Calculus BC free-response question 4.  I solved this problem correctly, but I don't know how to graph it.  Could you help explain how?

Comment: I would graph the base, which is easy, and visualize the solid.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am having trouble trying to graph the change that is happening. The lenght of the base is changing and that is the problem, just wanted to know how to make a good graph of this problem.

Comment: The base is $x$, s the cross-sectional area is $3x^2$. So the volume of a thin slice of width $dt$ is $3x^2\,dy$. "Add up" (integrate) $y=0$ to $6$. To do the actual integration, need to use fact that $x=(y/2)^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I got the integral, just having trouble drawing it on paper.

Comment: Well, three dimensional drawing is tough. The object has a sharp point at the origin.

Comment: @AndréNicolas should have been more clear in my post about drawing in real life.  IS there a primer for a FAQ or Walkthru I could read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Andre did the answer completely so I did just the picture of your solid:

[image]

Comment: @Mao Yiyi: Could you imagine the whole solid volume?

Comment: S: What I was saying was that your picture is the right answer to the question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks Andre. I wanted to be sure of it, however, you was the one who guide the OP finding the right path. I did nothing more. :-)

Comment: Nice and original presentation

Comment: @AdiDani: Thanks Adi. I am not at FB these days, but I saw your comment there.